# 510(k) Clearance Data Set seems to end as of June 1, 2023

Tags: openfda

Over the last month or so, I have downloaded the 510(k) dataset several times, and each time it seems to be lacking any 510(k)s decided after June 1, 2023. https://open.fda.gov/apis/device/510k/download/

Has anyone else experienced that?

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to our attention; we are investigating.

Answer (score 1):

We have checked the API & downloadable files and confirmed they contain the latest device clearance data.

Comment: Thank you very much.  My fault.  I had two copies and I was using an old one.  Sorry!